# How to pass parameter in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have ajax script which is working fine. Once it was success, I want to pass parameter like header("Location: tar.php?php=$value");

Till now I only know $("body").load("rumour.php"); Help me pass parameter like we do have in PHP

```
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_comment.php",
        data: { id1: id, comment1: comment },

            success: function(data) {
                $("body").load("rumour.php");
            }
   );
```

Comment: Look at window.location https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("body").html(data);
```

Comment: like this  `data: {rumour.php?id=value},   success: function(data) { $("body").html(data);}`